# complex-valued functions

Tags: complex-numbers

I think to have solved the following

$\Re(cf)=\Re [(\Re(c) + i\Im(c))(\Re(f) + i\Im(f))]
= \Re[\Re(c)\Re(f) + i\Re(c)\Im(f) + i\Im(c)\Re(f) + i^2 \Im(c)\Im(f)]=\Re(c)\Re(f) − \Im(c)\Im(f)$

but I can't proof

$-\Im(f)= \Re(i f)$ and $\Re(f)=\Im(if).$

Thank you so much

Comment: If $f=u+iv$ then $if = -v+iu$, so ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f = u + iv$ then $if = -v + iu$.

Therefore,

- $\Im(f) = v$
- $\Re(if) = -v$
- $\Re(f) = u$
- $\Im(if) = u$

The identities follow.